# Translate image-processing Matlab code into Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, code-review, matlab

I need some tips how to translate this Matlab code into Mathematica code.

```
%% Init
rgb = imread('rgb_test_pic.jpg');
rgb_data=reshape(rgb,[],3);

%% kmeans
k=10;
finish = 1;
data=double(rgb_data);
mittelwerte=double(data(randi(length(data(:,1)),1,k),:));
l=length(data(:,1));
i=0;
while finish
    dist=pdist2(data,mittelwerte,'euclidean');
    [a,b]=min(dist,[],2);
    for n=1:k
        mittelwert_new(n,:) = mean(data(b==n,:),'omitnan'); %#ok<SAGROW>
    end
    if max(abs(mittelwerte-mittelwert_new))<0.0001
        finish=0;
    end
end
```

I would like Mathematica code that does not use `GatherBy` and works with for any JPG image without an alpha channel.

Here´s my try with Mathematica.

```
Clear[MyKmeans]
MyKmeans[bild_, k_] :=
  Module[{daten, datennf, mittelwerte, dist, partition},
    daten = Flatten[ImageData[ImageResize[bild, 1000], "Byte"], 1];
    mittelwerte = RandomSample[daten, k];
    partition[_] := (
      dist = 
        Table[
          Nearest[
            mittelwerte -> Automatic, daten[[i]], 1, 
            DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance],
          {i, Length[daten]}] // Flatten;
      mittelwerte =
        Table[Mean[daten[[Flatten[Position[dist, i], 1]]]], {i, k}] // N);
    FixedPoint[partition, mittelwerte (*,sameTest->(Round[#1,1]==Round[#2,1]&)*)];
    Print[Round[mittelwerte]];]
```

Works mostly fine. I'm not quite sure what's the problem.

Comment: It is always helpful to present code that is working after copy. In this particular case: Please provide example values for `data`, `mittelwerte` and `k`.

Answer (score 2):

Due to lacking information, this can only be a pointer. `dist = pdist2(data, mittelwerte, 'euclidean');` translates into

```
dist = DistanceMatrix[data, mittelwerte];
```

or to

```
dist = DistanceMatrix[data, mittelwerte, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance];
```

if you would like to know how to specify the metric used.

A literal translation of `[a, b] = min(dist, [], 2);` would be

```
{a,b} = Min /@ dist
```

but this would assume that the vector `data` were 2-dimensional so that `dist` consists of only two rows.

The `for`-loop of yours might be replacable by

```
mittelwertNew = Table[
    Mean[DeleteCases[ Pick[ data , ??? ], NaN]]
]
```

where ??? is a suitable list of booleans. But I cannot make sense of it without having example data.

Comment: When the `DistanceMatrix` work on a matrix,it will regard every row is a element.

Comment: Don't use underscores in your variable names. `mittelwert_new` ought to be `mittelwertNew`.

Comment: Good point! Thanks.